# Cypress problems using 'contains' with embedded apostrophe

Tags: html, jquery-selectors, cypress

I'm using the latest version of Cypress (4.11.0). I'm having trouble selecting an entry on a dropdown via text in order to click on it. I'm pretty sure it's because of the embedded apostrophe, because I'm not having any trouble with the same kind of entry that doesn't contain an apostrophe.

In the code with the escaped apostrophe, I have tried multiple versions of escaping. I always need to use an odd number of backslashes, because otherwise I get a syntax error.

Here is my Cypress JS code:

```
cy.get('li:contains("Dick\'s Sporting Goods")').click({force: true});   // does not find the 'li'
cy.get('li:contains("Dick&apos;s Sporting Goods")').click({force: true});   // does not find the 'li'
cy.get('li:contains("Dick\\\'s Sporting Goods")').click({force: true});   // does not find the 'li'
cy.get('li:contains("Dick\\\\\'s Sporting Goods")').click({force: true});   // does not find the 'li'
cy.get('li:contains("Golf Galaxy")').click({force: true});   // finds the 'li'
```

Here is the generated HTML from Chrome Dev tools:

```
<ul class="MuiList-root MuiList-padding" role="menu" tabindex="-1" id="menu-list-grow" style="padding-top: 0px;">
    <li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false"
        style="padding-left: 0px; font-family: Archivo; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; background-color: transparent;">
        <img alt="dsg"
             src="..."
             style="margin-right: 10px; width: 40px;">Dick’s Sporting Goods<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false"
        style="padding-left: 0px; font-family: Archivo; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; background-color: transparent;">
        <img alt="gg"
             src="..."
             style="margin-right: 10px; width: 40px;">Golf Galaxy<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "*I'm having trouble selecting an entry...*" Can you edit your question to give more details about the sort of trouble you are having? It is an error message, blank screen, it doesn't get selected, it doesn't get submitted? It's difficult to help fix a problem when we don't know what it is!

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep it simple and should work:

```
 cy.get('li').contains("Dick's Sporting Goods").click();
 cy.contains("Dick's Sporting Goods").click();
```

Cypress is smart enough to handle this. More info: [link](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely simpler, and I have changed it to this. But it still doesn't work with the embedded apostrophe. If I take the apostrophe out of my code and out of the test, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh! It turns out the HTML was not using a normal apostrophe, I wasn't looking closely enough. I should have done copy and paste.

Thanks for everyone that tried to help!

Comment: Its always better to explain how HTML was not using normal apostrophe. I can relate to your answer that the `&apos;` was missing but would be great to always support your statement with a piece of code.